# Adding database relational information to map in Java database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to create a database that I will use in my Java application.

I have two entities:

Role[**ID**, name, description]

UIElement[**ID**, name, description]

They have a many to many relationship. i.e. A role can have many UIElements, and a UIElement can be set to a number of roles. The two are related in the following table:

Role_UI[**Role_Id**, **UI_ID**, property]

*Property* is a varchar(20) or a String, for example, Read/Create/Edit

In my java application (In the Role Object, since total ownership) I have the many to many set-up as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "role_ui",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ui_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
)
private Map<UIElement, String> uiElements = new HashMap<>();
```

Is this correct? Will the String in the map be the *property* field from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's workaround.

You need to create a new Entity:

Role_UI[Role_Id, UI_ID, property]

```
@Entity
class Role_UI{

   @ManyToOne
   Role role;
   @ManyToOne
   UIElement element;
   @Enumeration
   Permission property;
}


enum Permission{
   CREATE, EDIT, READ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate entity for ROLE_UI table and split the many-many to association into two one-to-many associations. Entity representing ROLE_UI table have the additional field (property).

[Java Persistence/ManyToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany)